# Cannot cancel meeting on behalf of sender using impersonation

Tags: exchangewebservices

We are not able to cancel meeting on behalf of sender using impersonation. We have given delegate access at user level & also given impersonation rights at exchange server level. Still when we try to Bind the original meeting id of sender from my mailbox, i get access denied exception. It seems we are missing some API code.

Any solution to this would be of great help.

Here is my code,

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string _recipientEmail = "elisabettas@contoso.com";
        static string _forwarderEmail = "bobk@contoso.com";
        static ExchangeService _senderCalendarExchangeService = ConnectExchangeServer("arleneh@contoso.com", "password"); // Meeting Sender - Originator
        static ExchangeService _forwarderCalendarExchangeService = ConnectExchangeServer(_forwarderEmail, "password"); // Meeting Forwarder - First receiver of the meeting who just forwards it.

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Sender creates a meeting invite & sends it to Forwarder.
            Appointment senderAppointment = new Appointment(_senderCalendarExchangeService);
            senderAppointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(new Attendee { Address = _forwarderEmail });
            senderAppointment.Subject = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            senderAppointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);

            // Forwarder scans the meeting invite from its Inbox.
            MeetingMessage senderMeetingMessage = GetSenderMeeting(senderAppointment.Subject);
            // Fills all default properties.
            senderMeetingMessage.Load();
            // Converts MeetingMessage object received in Mailbox to its equivalent appointment object in Calendar.
            Appointment appointment = Appointment.Bind(_forwarderCalendarExchangeService, senderMeetingMessage.AssociatedAppointmentId);
            // Finally, Forwarder forwards it.
            ResponseMessage responseMessage = appointment.CreateForward();
            responseMessage.ToRecipients.Add(_recipientEmail);
            responseMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();

            // Now, Sender sends an update to this meeting invite.
            senderAppointment = Appointment.Bind(_senderCalendarExchangeService, senderAppointment.Id);
            senderAppointment.Subject = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            senderAppointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
            // Forwarder again scans the updated meeting invite from its Inbox & forwards it.
            senderMeetingMessage = GetSenderMeeting(senderAppointment.Subject);
            // However this as subject has changed it has to send cancellation to end recipient.
            // Fills all default properties.
            senderMeetingMessage.Load();
            // Impersonate as sender in order to perform cancel meeting from its calendar.
            _forwarderCalendarExchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, senderMeetingMessage.Sender.Address);

            // At this line it throughs ServiceResponseException - Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
            appointment = Appointment.Bind(_forwarderCalendarExchangeService, senderMeetingMessage.AssociatedAppointmentId);
            appointment.CancelMeeting();
        }

        static ExchangeService ConnectExchangeServer(string emailAddress, string password)
        {
            ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
            exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(emailAddress, password);

            exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress);

            return exchangeService;
        }

        static MeetingMessage GetSenderMeeting(string senderAppointmentSubject)
        {
            SearchFilter.IsEqualTo senderMeetingMessageSearchBySubject = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(MeetingMessageSchema.Subject, senderAppointmentSubject);
            FindItemsResults<Item> senderMeetingRequestResult = _forwarderCalendarExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, senderMeetingMessageSearchBySubject, new ItemView(1));

            MeetingMessage senderMeetingMessage = senderMeetingRequestResult.First() as MeetingMessage;
            senderMeetingMessage.Load();

            return senderMeetingMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your Impersonating the Sender but your accessing the Forwarders Mailbox (using the Impersonated Senders credentials) hence you would get an error.

You should be doing

```
        appointment = Appointment.Bind(_forwarderCalendarExchangeService, senderAppointment.Id);
        appointment.CancelMeeting();
```

using

```
       senderMeetingMessage.AssociatedAppointmentId
```

would link to the Calendar object in the Mailbox the senderMeetingMessage is located in which in your case is the forwarding mailbox.

Cheers
Glen